# Why specifying a class in CSS breaks my code?

Tags: html, css, piano

I'm developing a small game, where there's a piano generated with pure HTML and CSS. I got the piano from [this amazing CodePen from Philip Zastrow](https://codepen.io/zastrow/pen/kxdYdk). And, while I was trying to adapt the styles, I found a strange behavior I couldn't understand. But, before I explain it, let me tell how the piano works.

It's a `<ul>` with a class (`set`), and the keys of the piano are `<li>` elements. Here's the structure:

```
<ul class="set">
  <li class="white b"></li>
  <li class="black as"></li>
  <li class="white a"></li>
  <li class="black gs"></li>
  <li class="white g"></li>
  <li class="black fs"></li>
  <li class="white f"></li>
  <li class="white e"></li>
  <li class="black ds"></li>
  <li class="white d"></li>
  <li class="black cs"></li>
  <li class="white c"></li>
</ul>
```

This is all the HTML in the CodePen (so, the "real" structure of the code is a `body` with a `ul` and some `li`). And the CSS just uses this: some styles are just referred to the `li` element (and not to the `set` class). For example, this one:

```
li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left
}
```

While this works, that has a problem. My game will have more lists. And I don't want them to get this style.

I thought the solution was easy: I could just specify that the `li` was inside a `set` class (because the `ul` has a `set` class). Imagine my surprise when I found that this broke the code.

```
/* This works */
li { /* Some styles */ }
/* But this doesn't */
.set li { /* Some styles */ }
```

In this snipped, I show you the code using `.set li` instead of just `li` (this is the only difference between this snipped and the original code in the CodePen).

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box
}

body {
  margin:0;
  background:#222
}

ul {
  height:18.875em;
  width:34em;
  margin:5em auto;
  padding:3em 0 0 3em;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #160801;
  border-radius:1em;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0)),url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/187/vwood.png);
  box-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset,0 1px rgba(212,152,125,0.2) inset,0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

.set li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left
}

ul .white {
  height:16em;
  width:4em;
  z-index:1;
  border-left:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  box-shadow:-1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset,0 0 5px #ccc inset,0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#eee 0%,#fff 100%)
}

ul .white:active {
  border-top:1px solid #777;
  border-left:1px solid #999;
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
  box-shadow:2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset,-5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset,0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%)
}

.black {
  height:8em;
  width:2em;
  margin:0 0 0 -1em;
  z-index:2;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset,0 -5px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset,0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,#222 0%,#555 100%)
}

.black:active {
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset,0 -2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset,0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#444 0%,#222 100%)
}

.a,.g,.f,.d,.c {
  margin:0 0 0 -1em
}

ul li:first-child {
  border-radius:5px 0 5px 5px
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px
}
```

```html
<ul class="set">
  <li class="white b"></li>
  <li class="black as"></li>
  <li class="white a"></li>
  <li class="black gs"></li>
  <li class="white g"></li>
  <li class="black fs"></li>
  <li class="white f"></li>
  <li class="white e"></li>
  <li class="black ds"></li>
    <li class="white d"></li>
    <li class="black cs"></li>
    <li class="white c"></li>
</ul>
```

I edited all the CSS, so I could use the piano just referring to the `set` class. Only the `.set li` doesn't work, all the other declarations work fine. My question is: why?

I'm not asking for the solution: [I asked the same in SO in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/548296/por-qu%C3%A9-no-puedo-determinar-la-clase-de-un-elemento-en-css/548329#548329) and [someone told me how I could solve the problem](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/548329/163659) (instead of `.set li`, using `.white, .black`). But my question is still present: why `.set li` doesn't work, if the `li` is inside an element with that class?

Thanks for reading this, and I hope anyone can help me discover why this doesn't work, because I simply don't understand it.

Comment: `float:left` is missing the closing `;` and in general if you have rules that come first in specificity, their css properties will have precedence over rules that have a lower specificity. The selector itself  `.set li` it's ok... I would make it even more specific like `.set > li` but maybe there are rules more specific setting the same css properties. For example margin is set on specific classes with selectors like `.black` and of course their setting will have precedence over the margin set by a more general rule like `.set li`. Unless you specify the attr as `!important` in the gen. rule

Comment: This is probably just a case of [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In some cases their selectors are more specific so they still take priority over your CSS. You would have to write `.set` in front of all the selectors to override all of them. Also your custom styles should be *last*, not first. If equal specificity, the last styling is applied.

Comment: @PeterKrebs You're right, it must be that. When I tested it, some days ago, I added `.set` to all the selectors, but I forgot to add it to a line, that says `.a,.g,.f,.d,.c { margin:0 0 0 -1em }`. I've just added `.set`
 in front of them too, and it worked. So, really thanks!

Comment: @DiegoDeVita What I don't understand is: if type of element has lower precedence than class, when I added the `.set` class reference, shouldn't `.set li` have more precedence than just `.black`, since there's type (`li`) + class (`.set`)? Btw, also thanks for your help!

Comment: the whole argument of css specificity I was talking about is perfectly explained in the mdn link shared by the other user. You can check by yourself there but to answer to the sepcific question, .black has more specificity over the element to be styled because it uses a class while the other is using the element type (li).

Comment: Really thanks to you, @DiegoDeVita and @PeterKrebs. I've fully understood the problem: when doing `.set li` instead of `li`, I was giving more specificity to that declaration, and because it was using `margin 0`, the other declarations also using `margin` (`.black` and `.a,.g,.f,.d,.c`) were left off, because `.set li` had preference. Really thanks! Now I finally understand what was happening.